# Selenium webdriver Disable WebRTC detection in firefox profile.setpreference

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**How Disable WebRTC detection in firefox**
" media.peerconnection.enabled" **using Selenium webdriver**

this is the code

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
 from time import sleep

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.set_preference( "general.useragent.override", tax )
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "xx.xx.xx.xx")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128)
profile.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", "false")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print "url: "
driver.get('http://www.example.com')
```

the profile.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", "false") dose not work only if i set it manually 
how to do that with Selenium

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use it as below:

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
 from time import sleep

 # init profile
 profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 

 # set proxy and other prefs.
 profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
 profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "xx.xx.xx.xx")
 profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128)
 # update to profile. you can do it repeated. FF driver will take it.

 profile.update_preferences()

 # You would also like to block flash 
 profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so',False)
 profile.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False)

 # save to FF profile
 profile.update_preferences()
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
 driver.get('http://www.google.com')
 :
 :
```

AFAIK, Problem in your code is, firefox profile can not typecast the string to boolean. These preferenece you are trying to set are boolean values and your tried to set it with string "false" . 
Note caps of False as its acceptable in python. You can also refer to prefs.js in Firefox profile dir. It will show all set preferences for given instance of firefox.

Also do check on compatibility of selenium and firefox version.